# add class to object 1, wait, add class to object 2 within for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to get a collection of elements with a class. I then wish to loop through each element in the collection in order to add a class.

However, I want it to add a class to the first in the collection, then wait 5 seconds before adding to the 2nd in the collection. And so on...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var boxs = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraph");

        for(let i = 0; i < boxs.length; i++){
            setTimeout(function () {
                boxs[i].classList.add("type");
            },5000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your `i` variable to calculate a suitable delay to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) (first execution after 5s, second after 10s, etc.):

```
for(let i = 0; i < boxs.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function () {
    boxs[i].classList.add("type");
  }, (i + 1) * 5000);
}
```

When you call `setTimeout`, you are just setting a timer for the execution of your callback. That's why you need to compute appropriate delays for each call.

Comment: Doesn't solve `boxs[i]` that will always be `boxs[boxs.length]` and not `boxs[0]`, `boxs[1]`, etc.

Comment: Ah, except no, because it does work with `let`, my bad

Comment: Today I learned. Lexical scope for the win. Good point, though.

Answer (score 0):

All the set timeouts run at the same time. The loop runs and sets each thing to run at 5 seconds. You need to add a delay by offsetting each iteration.

```
for(let i = 0; i < boxs.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function () {
    boxs[i].classList.add("type");
  },5000 * (i + 1));
}
```

Most people would use a queue

```js
// grab all the elements and put it into an array
const paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p"))

function runNext() {
  // wait 5 seconds
  window.setTimeout( () => {
    // remove the first item from array and set the class
    paras.shift().classList.add("type")
    // if items are remaining, set up the next timeout
    if (paras.length) runNext()
  }, 5000)
}

runNext()
```

```css
p { color: #CCC; }
p.type { color: #000; }
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
<p>Four</p>
<p>Five</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a closure for this, otherwise all the functions will execute when `i===boxs.length`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < boxs.length; i++) {
    ( num => setTimeout(function () {
        boxs[num].classList.add("type");
    }, 5000*num))(i)
}
```

EDIT

I just noticed that you used `let`, so actually you don't need a closure. Every loop will have its own scope. You can just use `5000*i`